# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  7pm UTC on the 24th (2pm EST) - now!

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place on Thursday the 24th at 7pm UTC, 2pm EST**

[(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=24&year=2011&hour=19&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

[(click here to join)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/299/tex-town-hall-chat)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 22nd-24th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=tex.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/299/tex-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript and a summary will be available.

Comment: Note of course the question thread on meta: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/949/questions-for-moderator-nominees

Comment: @JosephWright, absolutely, that's great.  This is by no means a replacement for that, a supplement if you will.

Comment: I'm fine with any time in the evening on any of the three days (22.-24.)

Comment: I've added answers for each day, to get a sense of which days are best.  If you want to use this system and want to say something about which times are best for you on each day, you can edit them (they are CW) to tell everyone about your preferred times.

Comment: @CharlesStewart, I've coordinated with the moderators already and done a best-fit based on their responses.

Comment: Can we *please* change it to: "TeX Town Hall Chat".  Without the proper capitalisation, it feels as though I ought to stride in through swinging doors, spit out some tobacco, and reholster my .44!

Comment: @AndrewStacey, done (FYI you should have the access to do so yourself as a moderator).  Did I mention that I have no domain knowledge here? (;

Comment: @Rebecca: Ah, another of those mysterious moderator powers that I had no idea that I had - until I'm about to lose them!  (Just another reason why I'm happy about giving up my super powers.).  Seriously, thanks for changing it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, no worries - I should have paid attention to the casing.

Comment: @Rebecca: OK, qns deleted.

Comment: @Andrew Pretty sure that's going to be my mental image of you from now on. Hope you've polished your spurs.

Comment: @Will: I guess I should change my gravatar then.  To be true to my current residency, I should replace the .44 by a double-headed axe.  Incidentally, why isn't your name on the list of candidates?  Theses are no excuse!

Comment: @Andrew: Excuse=[this](https://github.com/wspr/).  Don't ask him!

Comment: @Charles: In that case, you're next on my hit list.  It's Will or you - who's it going to be?

Comment: @Andrew: Err,  well ... I can't make the Town Hall Chat.  Yes, that's it!  Actually, sadly I don't think I will be free then.

Comment: @Charles: Feeble. Given that we've only a few hours left, it looks as though I'm going to have to hack in to a few people's openids and nominate them myself.

Answer (score 4):

As with the other town hall chats, <strike>I will be creating a "digest" version for the TeX Town Hall Chat</strike> Rebecca has created a "digest" version of the Town hall chat for us (thank you!). This will be posted as one large Meta question. The digest will contain all the questions and their answers, with none of the other conversation from the room.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests). Or for an example, look at the [AskUbuntu Town Hall Digest](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/948/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) or the [Gaming Town Hall Digest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1759/2252).

You can also discuss these digests with me in chat, in [the Town Hall Discussion room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

[Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek) has created the digest for us, and Andrew Stacey helped me post it. A giant thanks to both of them!

**[Here is the chat digest](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)**

Comment: Is there loads to do?  I'm sure we could figure out a way to bump you up to 125 rep to get it done more quickly!  Or you could post the whole thing in one answer and I'll chop it up for you.  (Or email it to me and I'll post it)

Comment: @Andrew: What needs to be done is copying and pasting; Rebecca already did the heavy lifting for me! [Join me in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion) to discuss helping if you're interested!

Answer (score 1):

I will be travelling on the dates in question and won’t have an internet connection so unfortunately I can’t participate.

But on the other hand we already have a few good candidates lined up and I wouldn’t vote for myself anyway (can we even do that?) so I don’t think my candidacy is at all crucial. I don’t think I’m a very good candidate anyway since I almost never visit the meta site.

Comment: Konrad, you should nominate yourself anyway!  You've provided a valuable SO perspective when you have visited meta.